# Laravel naming convention, same entity or separate entities?

Tags: laravel, naming-conventions, laravel-7

So I'm working on a realestate system, we have Properties and then we have Property Types (which can be house, restaurant, land etc). So the dilemma is: *do we treat Property Types as part of Properties or do we treat them as separate entities*?

### Controller:

`PropertiesController`
`PropertyTypesController`

or

`PropertiesController`
`TypesController`

### Model:

`Property`
`PropertyType`

or

`Property`
`Type`

### View:

`views/properties/index.blade.php`
`views/properties/show.blade.php`
`views/properties/edit.blade.php`
`views/properties/types/index.blade.php`
`views/properties/types/show.blade.php`
`views/properties/types/edit.blade.php`
`views/properties/types/create.blade.php`

or

`views/properties/index.blade.php`
`views/properties/show.blade.php`
`views/properties/edit.blade.php`
`views/properties/create.blade.php`

`views/property_types/index.blade.php`
`views/property_types/show.blade.php`
`views/property_types/edit.blade.php`
`views/property_types/create.blade.php`

Comment: So PropertyTypes are just records of all possible types?

Comment: Yes. And to expand on that idea, PropertyTypes has its own table and translations, and each property type is associated with certain fields (for example the Property Type "land" will have  fields "title", "description", "price" but can't have a field "floor" because it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: In my opinion Property and PropertyType are more descriptive and "feels" beyyer, but I guess this is also more of a personal thing. 

Both "Property and PropertyType" or  "Property  and Type" are correct, there is no false or correct answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **PropertyType** is better than **Type**

You should try to make your variables (or Class names) as descriptive as you can (keeping it short).
Instead of `$order->status` and `$type` it's better to use something like:

`$order->deliveryStatus` and `$itemType`

Because you never know when at some point you'll need to add different kind of 'status' or 'type'. Therefore you should go with more descriptive naming

Answer (score 2):

I think the most important question here is this.

Is there currently, or anytime in the future, a possibility that there exists another Model / Concept of Types? For example PaymentTypes or UserTypes or so on.

If you could already see the slightest possibility that this might happen, I would definitely go with the more verbose option PropertyTypes. Also keep in mind that when it comes to relations, you can still make them less verbose, to keep your code simple, like this for example.

```
public function types() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\PropertyType');
}
```